# Expected value of maximum of absolute values of two independent and identicall distributed standard normal random variates

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are  independent,  having both standard normal distribution, what is $E\left(\max(\left|X_1\right|,\left|X_2\right|\right)$?

Actually, holding similar condition there is no problem when calculating  $E(\max(X_1,X_2))$. Since $\max(X_1,X_2)=\frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_2+\left|X_1-X_2\right|)$ and taking expectation from both sides,   $E(\left|X_1-X_2\right|)$ can be  calculated following the fact that $\left|X_1-X_2\right|$  has  half-normal distribution. Using the same fashion for  $\max(\left|X_1\right|,\left|X_2\right|)$, yields $E(\left|(\left|X_1\right|-\left|X_2\right|)\right|)$, which seems difficult to calculate.
I have seen under [What is the expected value of $\min\{|X|,|Y|\}/\max\{|X|,|Y|\}$ assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030946/what-is-the-expected-value-of-min-x-y-max-x-y-assuming-x-and) a possible relevant post which does not helped.

Comment: Please tell us more about your thoughts? Where did you stuck?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2802696/.

Comment: Dear StubbornAtom many thanks. Any idea about the answer of the same question when one of the variables hold constant?